# How to create a helper function for queries in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I have a query similar to this:

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(
    (SELECT jsonb_agg(s) FROM ((SELECT column FROM my_table)) AS s),
    '[]'::jsonb
);
```

which returns all rows in json format:

```sql
[
    {
        "column": 1,
    },
    {
        "column": 2
    }
]
```

And if there are no rows, it returns a empty array instead of `null`.

I want to re-use this, but it would quickly become a mess to type out the whole thing everywhere. That's why I trying to create this `as_json` function:

```sql
-- DOESNT WORK
CREATE FUNCTION as_json(query ???)
    RETURNS jsonb
    LANGUAGE sql
AS $$
    SELECT COALESCE((SELECT jsonb_agg(s) FROM query AS s), '[]'::jsonb);
$$;
```

If I could make it work, using it would be as simple as

```sql
as_json(SELECT column FROM my_table)
```

Can I achieve something like that in postgresql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually quite easy to write something similar to [`query_to_xml()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-xml.html#FUNCTIONS-XML-MAPPING)

```
create or replace function query_to_jsonb(p_query text, p_include_nulls boolean default false)
  returns jsonb
as
$$
declare
  l_result jsonb;
  l_sql text;
begin
  if p_include_nulls then 
    l_sql := 'select jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(dt)) from ('||p_query||') as dt';
  else 
    l_sql := 'select jsonb_agg(jsonb_strip_nulls(to_jsonb(dt))) from ('||p_query||') as dt';
  end if;
  
  execute l_sql
    into l_result;
    
  return coalesce(l_result, '{}');
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

Then you can return the result of a query (string) as a JSON value, e.g.

```
select query_to_jsonb('SELECT column FROM my_table');
```

To remove NULL values from the result, use:

```
select query_to_jsonb('select col1, col2 from some_table', true);
```

Comment: Wow thanks. It still returns null if the query doesn't return rows though. I had to modify it to use `COALESCE` instead.